# wavefunction antisymmetry as a limit of a deeper geometric constraint

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

Recently there was an interesting reformulation of Pauli principle in terms of polytopes: http://physics.aps.org/articles/v6/8

My question is, can this suggest that fermionicity is not a fundamental property, but an emergent property of the quantum low-energy Hamiltonian?

**Bonus question:** Can this imply that Coleman-Mandula theorem doesn't really apply to physics, and hence supersymmetry is not as useful as we thought?

Comment: It seems that there are no such claims possible. By using the normal QM formalism this Klyachko finds some extra constraints for multi-particle systems. These extra constraints happen to be visualised using polygons. But the argument clearly needs fermionic statistics from the get-go.

Comment: The point that they make is that the fermionic harmonic oscillator shows a strong connection to the polygonal geometry when the inter-fermion interaction is slowly switched on, but is not exactly the same result as assuming the state is antisymmetric. So, if i understood the article correctly, this could actually be tested experimentally, because it *doesn't* give the same results as traditional fermionics